# Rateit plugin not working when used in Mustache.js template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, mustache

I am using **RateIt Pugin** in my **Mustache.js template** but it is not showing up any thing.

When i am using it RateIt directly in HTML its working fine

below is my mustache template

```
<script id="category_list" type="text/template">
  <li> Rate {{movie_name}}:
      <div  class="rateit">
      </div>
  </li> 
</script>
```

Below is my JS code to get the template and add it to main page

```
 var data={
            movie_name:'some movie'
        };
$.get('js/temp.html', function(template, textStatus, jqXhr) {
    var menu_list=Mustache.render($(template).filter('#category_list').html(), data);
    $('#movie_details_list').empty().append(menu_list);
    $.mobile.changePage( '#movie_details_page', { transition: "slide", changeHash: false });
});
```

this is my HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">
      <ul data-role="listview" id="movie_details_list" >
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fire `rateit()` after loading the template. I didn't understood your `result/template` logic and did some adjustments:

```
var template = $('#category_list').html();
Mustache.parse(template);
var data={
   movie_name:'Stack in the Galaxy'
};
$.get('temp.html', function( result, textStatus, jqXhr ) {
    var rendered = Mustache.render( template, data );
    $('#target').html( result );
    $('#movie_details_list').append( rendered );
    $('div.rateit, span.rateit').rateit(); // <-- start up RateIt
});
```